# Add undefined fields in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have created Mongo model like described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/

But it's like creating schema. I need to add fields, that I initially don't know. So I can't describe it in model. How I should be?

Comment: Solved. It is not neccesary to describe entire model. Problem was when I tried add entry via scaffolding code, so in view was "Form_for" tag. When I changed it to "Form_tag" and changed "f.label" and "f.text" to "label_tag" and "text_tag", problem was solved. Mongo began add dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check about dynamic fields. Depending on the ODM that you are using there are ways of implementing it. For MongoID you can check [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields). MongoMapper has a similar implementation as described in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongomapper/k_VwlaSK5XA).